# WPF Как воспроизвести видео из ресурсов с помощью MediaElement?

Tags: c#, wpf

Привет знатокам) нужна помощь. Как реализовать что-то такое как на картинке 1
[image: Пример]

Думал как-то так но не получается, ругает меня (
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [файл мультимедиа нельзя использовать как ресурс проекта](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/multimedia-overview)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, не знал. Но наверное можно, если сэмулировать стрим, но задача не тривиальная.